# C# Updating label with image

Tags: c#, label

I'm learning C# and kind of stuck at this point.
I made a form which has a label and a button.
When the button is clicked, an image should get loaded on the label and the label resizes to fit the image.
However, nothing happens and I don't think any errors are being generated either. What am I missing here?
I found the code to resize and load image on MSDN.
Here's the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ff = "C:\\anImage.png";

    try {
        label1.BackColor = Color.White; //this happens
        Image image1 = Image.FromFile(ff);
        label1.Size = new Size(image1.Width, image1.Height);  //does not happen
        label1.Image = image1; //does not happen
    }
    catch (Exception eee) {
        MessageBox.Show(eee.ToString()); //no messageBox comes up with any errors
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the image gets loaded correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `label1.AutoSize = false`.

Comment: Thanks! That Autosize worked. Could you please explain what happenned here? I am thinking that setting it to false should not allow it to get resized at run time, but it works in opposite way.

Comment: AutoSize means: Make the size fit the Text; if you assing a lot of thext with a large font you would seem some of your image, too..

Comment: @jeet: TaW is right. AutoSize makes the size of your label grow/shrink based on the size of the Text it is showing. If you would have provided a large string it would have grown to show more of the image. More info and some relevant sample code are available on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx).